# Cannot perform write functions in smart contract - invalid address?

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-development, addresses

I have the following simple smart contract...

```
contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;
    function set(uint x) {
        storedData = x;
    }
    function get() constant returns (uint retVal) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

Which I deploy with the following code in the geth console...

```
var source = "contract SimpleStorage...[code here]"
var compiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source)
var contract = web3.eth.contract(compiled.Coin.info.abiDefinition)
var storage = contract.new({from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: compiled.SimpleStorage.code, gas: 300000})
```

After the contract has been mined, I am able to access the contract functions via the storage object. I assumed that I could just call...

```
storage.set(10)
```

...to set the storedData variable. However every time I try this I get an "Invalid Address" error.

I'm sure that this is because I am attempting to perform a write operation on the internal state of the contract (read operations work fine).

I need to submit a transaction that mines the new state of the contract, however I can't figure out how to do this.

**How can I perform write transactions in smart contracts?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try setting

> web3.eth.defaultAccount = eth.accounts[0]

It sounds like your transaction doesn't know what account to use to sign the call. Any call that changes the state of the contract (write operation) requires a signed transaction.

An alternative approach would be to pass a 'transaction object' as the last argument to contract method:

```
storage.set(10,{from: accounts[0]});
```

Edit 1:

When I chose the 'from' account, I got the following error: 'authentication needed: password or unlock'. So I needed to run personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0],"password",15000). You can read about it at ['authentication needed: password or unlock' Error when trying to call smart contract method via web3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19122/authentication-needed-password-or-unlock-error-when-trying-to-call-smart-cont) .

Comment: I knew it would be simple! How would I do this without setting the defaultAccount? For example if I was using multiple accounts on the same geth instance?

Comment: You can call `web3.accounts` and store the results into an array. Then access the array for the specific account. When you call a method that executes a transaction and needs an account, pass an object that contains a `from`: `storage.set(10,{from: accounts[1]});`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. So simple! If the function has multiple parameters, is it just... `storage.set(a,b,c,d,{from: eth.accounts[0]})`?

Comment: Yes.  See the web3.js api docs: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction  Note the transactionObject.  This is what you can pass as the last argument to your contract call

Comment: and how to obtain the txID of the result?

Comment: `web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[0]` should be `eth.defaultAccount = eth.accounts[0]`

Comment: This worked for me as well. Just want to share how I changed my call to get a response based upon comments above in web3.js on Mac terminal: Original call: contractInstance.getStep() . New call:  contractInstance.getStep({from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}).