# Transaction to smart contract shows 'invalid address' error message

Tags: web3js, transactions, testrpc

I'm simply trying to transfer ETHER to a smart contract deployed on testrpc:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({to: "0xdbf5c15f21ae03f0e33c9058d3823d4e74a35be3", value: web3.toWei(100, "ether")});
```

Quering information from the contract works fine. Thus the address should be alright. However whenever I execute sendTransaction, I get this error:

[image: Error message in console]

Any suggestions what I can try to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either add `from:eth.coinbase,` before `to:` in your `sendTransaction` command or run `web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.coinbase` on your client terminal.
See this : [Cannot perform write functions in smart contract - invalid address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/cannot-perform-write-functions-in-smart-contract-invalid-address)

Comment: Thx a lot. Now it works!