# Invalid Address Error when interacting with a smart contract with metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask

I want to call the methods with metamask of this simple contract:

```
contract AssetPrices {
  mapping (uint => uint) public prices;
  uint public data;

  function EnterPrice(uint _time, uint _price){
  prices[_time] = _price;
  }

  function GetPrice(uint _time) returns (uint){
  data = prices[_time];
  return data;
  }

}
```

The contract is deployed at address 0xd884b7b7d6e21798814f218f2daa1054cff33ee5

The index.html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body class="container">
  <h1>A Simple METAMASK controlled contract</h1>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Check if Web3 has been injected by the browser:
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // You have a web3 browser! Continue below!
    startApp(web3);
  } else {
    alert("no web3 detected");
  }
})
function startApp(web3) {
  web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
  abi= JSON.parse('[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_time","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_price","type":"uint256"}],"name":"EnterPrice","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"data","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_time","type":"uint256"}],"name":"GetPrice","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"prices","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]');
  PriceContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
  ContractInstance = PriceContract.at('0xd884b7b7d6e21798814f218f2daa1054cff33ee5');
  // Enter new price
  ContractInstance.EnterPrice(25,150, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]});
  // Get the price you entered
  x = ContractInstance.GetPrice(25, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]});
}
})
</script>
</html>
```

However when I serve the page I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: invalid address

    at inputAddressFormatter (https://cdn.rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js:3920:11)
    at inputTransactionFormatter (https://cdn.rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js:3746:20)
    at https://cdn.rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js:5005:28
    at Array.map (native)
    at Method.formatInput (https://cdn.rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js:5004:32)
    at Method.toPayload (https://cdn.rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js:5030:23)
    at Eth.send [as sendTransaction] (https://cdn.rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js:5055:30)
    at SolidityFunction.sendTransaction (https://cdn.rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js:4121:26)
    at SolidityFunction.execute (https://cdn.rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js:4207:37)
    at startApp (http://127.0.0.1:8000/:27:20)
```

Comment: I have a similar problem and doesn't exist a lot information about the invalid address errors. The only what i found is the `web3.eth.accounts` "solution", but this doens't work for me, cause metamask put the correct account with injected web3.

Maybe somethign like [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15575/transaction-to-smart-contract-shows-invalid-address-error-message?rq=1) can help you, if you found the answer write here again ^^

Comment: Try to set default account and send transaction in callback from `web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accounts) {...}`. Maybe, it'll help.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem when testing the contract from 'geth console'.

I found out the problem was not having set the default account. You have to assign a default account and unlock it, like this:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]
personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.defaultAccount)
contractObj = web3.eth.contract(contractABI).at(contractAddr)
contractObj.method(args...)
```

I guess the contract uses the default account to pay the gas used by the contract.

Comment: This worked perfectly. But I am still baffled as to why would I need to unlock the account to get the encoded ABI of a method even before I call it. Any info on this?

Answer (score 8):

```
PriceContract.web3.eth.defaultAccount=PriceContract.web3.eth.coinbase
```

You need to set the default account of the contract too. or if contractinstance is what you use to call the functions

```
Contractinstance.web3.eth.defaultAccount=Contractinstance.web3.eth.coinbase
```

Answer (score 5):

One reason this error can be thrown is if the `web3.eth.accounts` array is empty, which happens if the user has not signed in to MetaMask.

Comment: The array is not empty - it has exactly one account

Answer (score 5):

Update from January 2019:

The `Invalid address` error can also happen if you haven't called `window.ethereum.enable();` yet.

Comment: Thank you man! I've been looking for solution for a day now :)

Answer (score 1):

web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
console.log(web3.eth.defaultAccount)
This prints the address fine.

but...
 var address = web3.eth.defaultAccount

When i pass the address or web3.eth.defaultAccount into a smart contract method, it gives invalid address.

I want to know if anyone faced similar issue and how to go about solving this invalid address in the smartcontract methods.

Comment: Please ask a separate question

Answer (score 1):

Have a same problem. Firefox has installed Metamask and web3 variable is already setted, but on DOMContentLoaded time web3.eth.accounts[0] is empty. My solution was

```
  if (web3.eth.accounts.length === 0){
    var fckdFirefox = setInterval(() => {
      if (web3.eth.accounts.length > 0) {
        web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]
        window.contract = web3.eth.contract(bsABI).at(bsAddress)
        clearInterval(fckdFirefox)
      }
      else {
       console.log(Date.now(),  " WTF?");
      }
    }, 100)
  }
```

Output is

```
  1557269408292  WTF? main.js:30
  1557269408391  WTF? main.js:30
  1557269408493  WTF? main.js:30
  1557269408593  WTF? main.js:30
  1557269408693  WTF? main.js:30
  1557269408794  WTF? main.js:30
```

E.g. web3.eth.accounts assigned after ~600ms

Answer (score 1):

The call to `web3.eth.accounts` does not return a list of accounts, as per the [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth-accounts.html#web3-eth-accounts):

[image]

Fetch the active user account like so:

```
var userAccount = null;
web3.eth.getAccounts(async function(error, accounts) {

        if (error == null && accounts.length > 0) {
          userAccount = accounts[0];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

add
`window.ethereum.enable();`
in the your html file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The root cause was here:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.coinbase
```

Later you will have to unlock the account which runs the tx, but it error message in that case is more explanatory:

```
personal.unlockAccount("0x62f8dc8a5c80db6e8fcc042f0cc54a298f8f2ffd")
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using either **constant** or **payable** modifier.

```
function GetPrice(uint _time) constant returns (uint) {...}
// or
function GetPrice(uint _time) payable returns (uint) {...}
```

Since **GetPrice** doesn't change a state, probably best to use **constant** so you don't have to pay a gas cost.

But, if you want to test integration with **metamask**, you can try **payable** and see if you get **metamask** to popup with the gas price of the transaction.