# Invalid Address Error when interacting with a smart contract & Why it works with metacoin

Tags: truffle

I solved the error accroding to [Invalid Address solution](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19524/invalid-address-error-when-interacting-with-a-smart-contract-with-metamask)

> PriceContract.web3.eth.defaultAccount=PriceContract.web3.eth.coinbase

The contract I run was a very simple set-get variable which I adapted according to the truffle metacoin sample.

My question is: why metacoin runs ok and my contract needs to assign the defaultAccount?

In both cases I run the contract against a local geth node.

Answer (score 1):

I found what was different between metacoin and my contract.

In metacoin when calling sendCoind a last parameter is added: 
{from: account}

Now my app runs without setting the defaultAccount.