# authentication needed: password or unlock

Tags: web3js, blockchain, password, microsoft-azure, error

We're using Microsoft Azure, and NodeJS on the server. When we address Microsoft Azure via NodeJS, sometimes we get the 'Password or Unlock' error. But when we use Truffle and address the same setter, everything works fine. What could be the possible problem and what does this error mean as I've unlocked my account.

This is my code:

```
this.web3.eth.getCoinbase()
        .then(coinbase => {
            console.log("Setter method started!");
            return this.contract.methods
                .setCopyright(
                    queryParams.certificateNumber,
                    queryParams.typeString,
                    queryParams.nameOfObject,
                    queryParams.firstName,
                    queryParams.secondName,
                    queryParams.lastName
                )
                .send({
                    from: coinbase,
                    gas: 4600000,
                    gasPrice: '22000'
                });
        })
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(err => {
            reject(err);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

When sending a transaction, you don't "unlock personal", you unlock the account that sends the transaction.

In this case, you could do:

```
return web3.personal.unlockAccount(ADDRESS, PASSWORD, TIME (if needed) );
.then(do whatever you want after that)
```

Comment: Sorry, but i know about it. I does it, and my problem it is not problem "unlock accounted" , when i ask my setter function sometimes i have  error "authentication needed: password or unlock". But my account is unlocked. That error only on my nodejs  project,  but my setter function on truffle call correctly. Why?

Comment: Abvouisly, if your node says that your account is not unlocked, it is not. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

i recommend this solution

```
personal.unlockAccount(Address, Password, 0)
```

0 is unlock no time limit

Comment: `invalid argument 1: json: cannot unmarshal hex string without 0x prefix into Go value of type hexutil.Bytes`

Comment: Address is 0x~~~ you should make account first

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.If someone needs it in the future: First i created multi-member(Ethereum Leader and Ethereum Member) in Azure and it did not work. Then I removed all groups multi-member and create one group "Blockchain". And is correctly worked.