# Cryptocurrency Tutorial: how to transfer on the geth console?

Tags: contract-development, tokens

I build, compiled and deployed (to Testrpc) the token contract from the [cryptocurrency tutorial](https://ethereum.org/token).

The token offers the `transfer(addres _to, uint256 value)` method, which I would like to call from coinbase in the `node` console.

```
> contractDeployed.transfer
{ [Function: bound ]
  request: [Function: bound ],
  call: [Function: bound ],
  sendTransaction: [Function: bound ],
  estimateGas: [Function: bound ],
  getData: [Function: bound ],
  'address,uint256': [Circular] }
> 
> 
> contractDeployed.transfer(web3.eth.accounts[1], 100)
Error: invalid address
    at inputAddressFormatter (/home/mzh/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/formatters.js:273:11)
    at inputTransactionFormatter (/home/mzh/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/formatters.js:99:20)
    at /home/mzh/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:89:28
    at Array.map (native)
    at Method.formatInput (/home/mzh/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:88:32)
    at Method.toPayload (/home/mzh/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:114:23)
    at Eth.send [as sendTransaction] (/home/mzh/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:139:30)
    at SolidityFunction.sendTransaction (/home/mzh/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js:170:26)
    at SolidityFunction.execute (/home/mzh/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js:256:37)
    at repl:1:18
```

What is wrong with the address of `accounts[1]`?

```
> web3.eth.accounts[1]
'0xf6efe9d4c094be73dd5b2137e1c34032a1ea88e3'
```

How else to execute the transfer?

---

I also tried the instructions from the TESTRPC helpfile to unlock accounts at startup:

```
mzh@~ $ node_modules/.bin/testrpc --secure -u 0 -u 1
EthereumJS TestRPC v4.1.3 (ganache-core: 1.1.3)

Available Accounts
==================
(0) 0x0e7088e20e8d7e23a2ec6704104fbcc0e6c61845
(1) 0xa27b21423aeab486b0eb9d24d36dc354813754ce
(2) 0x6769222c45b93ca010b911842f893b8f3c862f25 
(3) 0xe4dcd88080804ea5f047fabe609dd8236090f75c 
(4) 0xca26648402c7446179d9d76fbc736f817d43f9fe
```

Clearly, accounts 0 and 1 are unlocked from the start. Still, I can't transfer from account 0 to 1.

```
> contractDeployed.transfer(web3.eth.accounts[1], 100)
Error: Error: could not unlock signer account
    at StateManager.queueTransaction (/home/mzh/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:83073:21)
    at GethApiDouble.eth_sendTransaction (/home/mzh/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:82631:14)
```

---

I got the inspiration for the solution from [this question.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/cannot-perform-write-functions-in-smart-contract-invalid-address)

The call to `transfer` requires an additional, implicit argument

```
> contractDeployed.transfer(web3.eth.accounts[1], 100, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]})
'0xcc2dda4270217201989495abfc3a9953ebfb8f51b81dbcb80e3aec52d7e225bb'
```

Comment: As you have discovered, the complain about the address about the missing {from: ...}. Also see a similar question here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/8736/20451

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transfer ether from one account to another account, you can use this:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:web3.eth.accounts[0],to:web3.eth.accounts[1],value:1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[1]` or `personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[1])`
Or both.

Comment: I tried it, but I get a very strange error which I can not understand

Comment: Really strange but actually i use all the commangs that you do but without preceeding `web3.` Can you try all the same with no `web3.` prefix?

Comment: I work in the node console, not the geth console. it needs `web3.` prepended.

Comment: I found the solution, see edited question.